# Two sensors available for same type in Android

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S3. When I retrieved the available sensors:

I got a result like below:

```
 LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer                    TYPE_ACCELEROMETER        
 AK8975C 3-axis Magnetic field sensor              TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD        
 iNemoEngine Orientation sensor                    TYPE_ORIENTATION          
 CM36651 Light sensor                              TYPE_LIGHT            
 CM36651 Proximity sensor                          TYPE_PROXIMITY            
 LSM330DLC Gyroscope sensor                        TYPE_GYROSCOPE             
 iNemoEngine Gravity sensor                        TYPE_GRAVITY               
 iNemoEngine Linear Acceleration sensor-S/W        TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION   
 iNemoEngine Rotation_Vector sensor                TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR     
 LPS331AP Pressure Sensor                          TYPE_PRESSURE            
 Rotation Vector Sensor                            TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR        
 Gravity Sensor - software sensor                  TYPE_GRAVITY              
 Linear Acceleration Sensor                        TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION   
 Orientation Sensor                                TYPE_ORIENTATION           
 Corrected Gyroscope Sensor                        TYPE_GYROSCOPE
```

STMicroelectronics seems to be the default one and sensors provided by Google Inc and Samsung Inc may be the secondary sensors. 
When I used getVendor() method, it returned STMicroelectronics(being the hardware default sensor) and Samsung. But when I registered both of the sensors, the onSensorChanged() was called that returned the orientation values(pitch, roll and azimuth) with great difference.

Example, I got the following values at the same timestamp(with difference of few seconds).

```
                         pitch:       roll:                   azimuth:
Samsung                 0.5917465    -4.212                   84.583
STMicroelectronics      0.0865345    -3.88854                 356.825
```

Any idea of why there is a difference in both or should we always monitor both the hardware and software sensors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2 sensors are provided by the 2 vendors as mentioned by madhus. It can be obtained using the code:

```
List<Sensor> gyro =mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE); 
for(int i=0;i<gyro.size();i++) { 
Log.d(TAG,"The vendor is: " +gyro.get(i).getVendor() + " **" +gyro.get(i).getVersion());
}
```

I got the vendors as STMicroElectronics and google Inc for all the sensors, except orientation(Samsung Inc and STMicroElectronics). However, as the default and hardware sensor is STMicroElectronics, I am using that.

Answer (score 2):

Accelerometer, Magnetic, Light, Proximity, Gyroscope, Pressure, Gravity, these are hardware-sensors.

'iNemoEngine xxx' should be a kind of 'virtual sensor', implemented by Google in ICS.

linear accelerometer, rotation-vector, orientation, these are software sensor implemented using sensor fusion algorithm.

http://electronicdesign.com/ios/understanding-virtual-sensors-sensor-fusion-context-aware-applications
http://www.sensorplatforms.com/which-sensors-in-android-gets-direct-input-what-are-virtual-sensors/
http://www.thousand-thoughts.com/2012/03/android-sensor-fusion-tutorial/

Comment: How will I know the default sensor and which one should I use ? @madhus

Answer (score 2):

The sensors object will be a list of all available sensors on the device.

To check for a specific sensor, use one of the other sensor constants such as, TYPE_TEMPERATURE, TYPE_RELATIVE_HUMIDITY or TYPE_PRESSURE.

There's also the getDefaultSensor() method. Passing a specific sensor constant to it will also determine whether a sensor is available on a device.

And if a device has more than one sensor of a given type, one of the sensors will be set as the default sensor. If there is no default sensor set, getDefaultSensor() will return null, thus indicating that the sensor is not present.

For example, the code to check for a gyroscope sensor using the getDefaultSensor() method could look something like this.

```
if (mSensorMgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) != null) 
{
   // Yesssss...gyroscope  sensor available
} 
else 
{
   // There's no gyroscope on this device :(
}
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: Hi, I used the code snippet                              List<Sensor> gyro =mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);            for(int i=0;i<gyro.size();i++)
        {
     Log.d(TAG,"The vendor is: " +gyro.get(i).getVendor() + " **" +gyro.get(i).getVersion());}                                        I am getting STMicroelectronics and Google Inc and Samsung Inc(only in case of Orientation) as vendor names. Any suggestion on which is better to use and why?  @madhus